# Массив указателей на базовый класс

Tags: c++, полиморфизм

Добрый день! У меня возник следующий вопрос. Имеется базовый класс, у которого есть три наследника. В четвертом классе создаются объекты производных классов и осуществляется выполнение методов для каждого из этих объектов. Как можно реализовать выполнение этих методов просто в цикле, пробегая по массиву указателей на эти объекты? Заранее благодарен!

```
class Base{
  public:
  int n;
  virtual void cleanarrays()=0;

};

class A : public Base{
  public:

  void cleanarrays();
  ar1[n];
};

class B : public Base{
  public:
  void cleanarrays();
  ar2[n];
};

class C : public Base{
  public:
  void cleanarrays();
  ar3[n];
};

class MyClass{
  public:
  A a;
  B b;
  C c;
  void cleanarrays();
};

void MyClass::cleanarrays(){ 
   a.cleanarrays();
   b.deletehists();
   c.deletehists();
}
```

Comment: Эээ... А как вы пробовали? Я не представляю себе, как можно сделать неправильно.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <vector>

class Base{
public:
    int n;
    virtual void cleanarrays()=0;
};

class A : public Base{
public:

    virtual void cleanarrays() override {}
};

class B : public Base{
public:
    virtual void cleanarrays() override {}
};

class C : public Base{
public:
    virtual void cleanarrays() override {}
};

class MyClass{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        m_items.push_back(new A());
        m_items.push_back(new B());
        m_items.push_back(new C());
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < m_items.size(); i++)
        {
            delete m_items[i];
        }
    }

    std::vector<Base*> m_items;

    void cleanarrays();
};

void MyClass::cleanarrays(){
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m_items.size(); i++)
    {
        m_items[i]->cleanarrays();
    }
}

int main()
{
    MyClass someClass;
    someClass.cleanarrays();

    return 0;
}
```